# Type hint for a file or file-like object?

Tags: python, type-hinting

Is there any correct type hint to use for a file or file-like object in Python? For example, how would I type-hint the return value of this function?

```
def foo() -> ???:
    return open('bar')
```

Answer (score 372, accepted):

Use either the `typing.TextIO` or `typing.BinaryIO` types, for files opened in text mode or binary mode respectively.

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.IO):

> #### *class* `typing.IO`
>
> Wrapper namespace for I/O stream types.
>
> This defines the generic type `IO[AnyStr]` and aliases `TextIO` and `BinaryIO` for respectively `IO[str]` and `IO[bytes]`. These representing the types of I/O streams such as returned by `open()`.

Comment: Generically, maybe typing.IO as the type description?

Comment: None of these seem to work for me: `def f() -> IO: return open('test')` gives "Expected type 'IO', got 'TextIOWrapper[str]' instead" in PyCharm.

Comment: @Marein what about `IO[str]`?

Comment: The same I'm afraid. I'm also noticing that iterating over the lines in a file gives "Expected 'collections.iterable'".

Comment: @Marein I suggest that you post a new question with a [mcve] because your code works fine for me, even using PyCharm.

Comment: Reproduced @Marein's issue in PyCharm community 2017.2: https://i.imgur.com/Ai4sVQl.jpg

Comment: Why does `BufferedReader` not come under the `IO` type? Mypy keeps saying that it got BufferedReader, but expects `Optional[IO[Any]]`.

Comment: The documentation is a bit confusing, it indicates a deprecation, but i’m not entirely sure what is covered by it, the optimist interpretation that it’s only about the typing.io namespace, but i’m not keen on being too optimistic when programming.

Comment: @Tshirtman I think you can be a optimistic about this. I found [this](https://bugs.python.org/issue42001) issue regarding the deprecation and it seems to be clearer about `typing.io` being the namespace to be deprecated because `typing.io.BinaryIO` and others also exist and were mostly used directly from the `typing` namespace, e.g., `typing.BinaryIO`.

Comment: @mxmlnkn indeed, that bug certainly disambiguates it, thanks :)

Comment: @Tshirtman In the Python documentation, a deprecation notice sometimes pertains to the respective class, method or function as a whole, but more typically pertains only to some aspect of it, such as an optional parameter that will no longer exist at some future time. In the present case, it is only that `typing.IO` etc. are currently still also available elsewhere but will not continue to do so.

Comment: none of these types are recognized pyt plain-jane Python so I have no idea why anyone is suggesting these for function annotations.

Comment: Using `io.TextIOWrapper` fixed the issue `Expected type 'IO', got 'TextIOWrapper[str]' instead` I had with Pyright.

Answer (score 56):

The short answer:

- You need to be explicit.  That is `from typing import TextIO` not just `from typing import *`.
- Use `IO` to mean a file without specifying what kind
- Use `TextIO` or `BinaryIO` if you know the type
- You cannot currently specify it be opened for write or its encoding.

As an example:

```
from typing import BinaryIO

def binf(inf: BinaryIO):
    pass

with open('x') as f:
    binf(f)
```

gives an inspection error (in PyCharm) of `Expected type 'BinaryIO', got 'TextIO' instead`

Comment: Can you do an `open` without specifying a file to open?

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisT. what’s your use-case?

Comment: Having a progressive system where you grab an 'open' with a promise of providing things later is an interesting question.   Please ask it as a question.

Answer (score 7):

If you're annotating the type of a parameter, consider *not* using [`typing.IO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.IO), [`typing.TextIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TextIO), or [`typing.BinaryIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.BinaryIO).

They risk being overly restrictive to the caller, because they include things that you often don't actually need, [like `.encoding` and `.newlines`](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/5ee46bd291997d2060890e566677ffb2dbdd94ca/stdlib/typing.pyi#L765).

Instead, consider defining your own [`typing.Protocol`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol). This lets you only require the parts of the "file-like" interface that you *actually* need.

So, for example, instead of doing this:

```py
def foo(file_like: typing.TextIO) -> None:
    read_str = file_like.read()
    # ...
```

Consider doing this:

```py
class TextFileLike(typing.Protocol):
    def read() -> str:
        ...

def foo(file_like: TextFileLike) -> None:
    read_str = file_like.read()
    # ...
```

Some Python core developers give this advice on https://github.com/python/typing/discussions/829.

> These [`typing.IO`, `typing.TextIO`, and `typing.BinaryIO`] classes were meant to model the concept of a "file object", but when you start looking at how "file objects" are really used across the Python library system, you quickly realize that there's a ton of variation in what exactly you can do with them.

The downside to this `typing.Protocol` strategy is that it restricts your ability to change your implementation later on. For example, if you decide later that you want to call `.readline()` instead of `.read()`, and you didn't include `.readline()` in your original `typing.Protocol`, you'll need to make a breaking change to your interface. In other words, it's a tradeoff between being too restrictive to your callers up-front and causing API usability problems, or coupling the interface too tightly to your implementation and causing breaking changes down the line.