# How should a NamedTemporaryFile be annotated?

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I tried `typing.IO` as suggested in  [Type hint for a file or file-like object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38569401/562769), but it doesn't work:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
from typing import IO

def example(tmp: IO) -> str:
    print(tmp.file)
    return tmp.name


print(example(NamedTemporaryFile()))
```

for this, mypy tells me:

```
test.py:6: error: "IO[Any]" has no attribute "file"; maybe "fileno"?
```

and Python runs fine. So the code is ok.

Comment: The problem is that the object returned by `NamedTemporaryFile` is not really _file-like_. It has only `close`, `delete`, `file` and `name` public methods, when `typing.IO` has `read`, 'write', 'seek' and others.

Comment: @sanyassh The documentation for `NamedTemporaryFile` says it returns a file-like object. Moreover, the object does have `read`, `write`, and `seek`. `NamedTemporaryFile` totally conforms to the `IO` protocol, and mypy even acknowledges this. The problem is that `NamedTemporaryFile` has at least one extra attribute (`file`) that isn't available on `IO`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think this can be easily type hinted.

If you check the definition of `NamedTemporaryFile`, you'll see that it's a function that ends in:

```
return _TemporaryFileWrapper(file, name, delete)
```

And `_TemporaryFileWrapper` is defined as:

```
class _TemporaryFileWrapper:
```

Which means there isn't a super-class that can be indicated, and `_TemporaryFileWrapper` is "module-private". It also doesn't look like it has any members that make it a part of an existing `Protocol` `*` (except for `Iterable` and `ContextManager`; but you aren't using those methods here).

I think you'll need to use `_TemporaryFileWrapper` and ignore the warnings:

```
from tempfile import _TemporaryFileWrapper  # Weak error

def example(tmp: _TemporaryFileWrapper) -> str:
    print(tmp.file)
    return tmp.name
```

---

If you really want a clean solution, you could [implement your own](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64185811/3000206) [`Protocol`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol) that includes the attributes you need, and have it also inherit from `Iterable` and [`ContextManager`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.ContextManager). Then you can type-hint using your custom `Protocol`.

---

`*` It was later pointed out that it does fulfil `IO`, but the OP requires attributes that aren't in `IO`, so that can't be used.

Comment: It is a part of the `IO` protocol. The problem in this example is that the `IO` protocol doesn't provide the `file` attribute.

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon Updated, although that doesn't change much. It fulfills `IO`, but still isn't what the OP needs.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to use:

```
import typing

def example(tmp: typing.IO[typing.Any]) -> str:
    print(tmp.file)  # type: ignore
    return tmp.name  # type: ignore
```

Admittedly, it's flawed in terms of strong typing, but this may be the best case approach?