# Python argument type specification for files

Tags: python-3.x, documentation, typing

I know, for example, that a function can be written to let know its argument is `str`:

```
def myfunc(s: str) -> None:
```

I search the documentation of `typing` but couldn't find anything about files as arguments.

How can I specify something as the following:

```
def use_file(a_file: ???) -> None:
```

where `???` is a binary file (as one created with `open("data", "rb")`)?

Comment: You can always look in the TypeShed to see how the standard library is defined: https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/390634b96b5910d0d566cc2763cf75d2f07067f6/stdlib/builtins.pyi#L1212-L1297.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type hint for a file or file-like object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38569401/type-hint-for-a-file-or-file-like-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `typing` module provides specific types for file-like objects. Your question is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38569401/type-hint-for-a-file-or-file-like-object).

```py
from typing import IO, TextIO, BinaryIO

# Answer to the question
# If your function only accepts files opened in binary mode 
def use_file(a_file: BinaryIO) -> None:
    ...

# If your function only accepts files opened in text mode
def use_file(a_file: TextIO) -> None:
    ...

# If your function accepts files opened in both modes
def use_file(a_file: IO) -> None:
    ...
```